# How to make a new div for every response from JSON API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

(Sorry if the title doesn't make sense, I wasn't sure how to word it.)

I have an API that returns a players friends list. It ends up looking something like this:

```
{
    "friendslist": {
        "friends": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561197960430929",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1486338170
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561197962297457",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1485227275
            },
            {
                "steamid": "76561197977344631",
                "relationship": "friend",
                "friend_since": 1484606628
            },
            ...
```

So I was wondering how I would make a new div for every response from the API so I can display their friends list? For every player there could be a different number of items returned from the API, depending on their friends list length, so I wasn't sure how I would go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated :)

Also if this question has been asked before, please link it because I wasn't sure how to word the google search to see if I could find something similar to my question.

(I'm using JavaScript/jQuery if that helps at all)

Comment: you'd create a new div on every iteration through `result.friendslist.friends`

Comment: how do you get all the players? Do you make a friends-list-request on click or do you iterate trough all the players...

Comment: @JaromandaX So how would I loop through `result.friendslist.friends` to find every iteration?

Comment: using a `for` loop or `result.friendslist.friends.forEach`

Comment: @Miro Right now it the API just returns it but I don't know what to do with it to make it do anything, so right now it does neither of those

Comment: @JaromandaX ok I'll try that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a simple [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Iterate through the response, creating a new element for each friend and appending it to the body.

```
result.friendslist.friends.forEach(function(friend){
    var friendDiv = document.createElement('div');
    friendDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(friend.steamid));
    document.body.appendChild(friendDiv);
});
```

*NB: You could make this more performant by doing only a single append to the body if you created a wrapper element and filled that with the friends before appending it. Like this:*

```
var wrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
result.friendslist.friends.forEach(function(friend){
    var friendDiv = document.createElement('div');
    friendDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(friend.steamid));
    wrapperDiv.appendChild(friendDiv);
});
document.body.appendChild(wrapperDiv);
```

PS. Please note that `forEach` is part of ES5 and thus, [not available for IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=es5). You could use a `for` loop in its place, or use a [polyfill](http://adamish.com/blog/archives/876).

Comment: So I have a div that I was planning on putting all of the other divs into with the id `friends-body`, so if I wanted to fill that up with the divs created with the forEach loop, would I just replace  `var wrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');` with `var wrapperDiv =  document.getElementById('friends-body')`?

Comment: Nevermind I tried it and that worked. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code to get you started. `var json` is your actual response.

```js
var json = "{\r\n    \"friendslist\": {\r\n        \"friends\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"steamid\": \"76561197960430929\",\r\n                \"relationship\": \"friend\",\r\n                \"friend_since\": 1486338170\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"steamid\": \"76561197962297457\",\r\n                \"relationship\": \"friend\",\r\n                \"friend_since\": 1485227275\r\n            },\r\n            {\r\n                \"steamid\": \"76561197977344631\",\r\n                \"relationship\": \"friend\",\r\n                \"friend_since\": 1484606628\r\n            }]\r\n            }}";
          
data = JSON.parse(json);

$.each(data.friendslist.friends, function(i,item){
  $('body').append( '<div>SteamId: ' + item.steamid + ' | ' + item.friend_since   + ' | ' + item.relationship + '</div>');
});
```

```css
div{
  padding:10px;
  margin:1px;
  background:teal;
  color:white;
  font-family: Roboto,Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with map function.

```
var friendList = {
    "friends": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561197960430929",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1486338170
        },
        {
            "steamid": "76561197962297457",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1485227275
        },
        {
            "steamid": "76561197977344631",
            "relationship": "friend",
            "friend_since": 1484606628
        }
    ] 
}
friendList.friends.map(function(key, value){
  // key will be the index of the array and value will be the item in the list  
   // create the div and append it to the parent element. 


})
```